# bindParam to a limit gives always limit 0

Tags: php, sql, yii

I would like to use the function limit for in a PDO statement, and bind a value to the limit :

```
$limit=1000;
$topResult = $db->createCommand()
 ->select('*')
 ->from('table1')
 ->order('popularity DESC')
 ->limit(':limit')
 ->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT)
 ->queryAll();
```

However, it seems that the limit is always 0 , regardless of the value of the variable $limit
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Which query builder are you using?

Comment: According to [this documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#limit()-detail) the parameter for the `limit()` function must be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass your `limit` variable to the `limit()` call:

```
$topResult = $db->createCommand()
 ->select('*')
 ->from('table1')
 ->order('popularity DESC')
 ->limit($limit)
 ->queryAll();
```